How does "Automatically reformat when completing code" work on Xcode?
in Settings on Xcode, there is an option Text Editing> Editing > Automatically reformat when completing code. What does it do? I enabled it, but I didn't see the code is formatted after typing some code.
Is it supposed to work like format on save, but completing code instead?
Also, Does Xcode support format on save?

completing refers to auto-completion so it's supposed to format the code that gets inserted when you select an auto-completion option. That said, I don't have this option checked but it seems to format the code anyway (using Xcode 16)

At least one of the things this setting does, is add hard line breaks when you autocomplete code.
For example, suppose I have set these settings

I purposefully chose a small number like 30 and enabled the reformatting guide so it is clear what is going on.
If you try to select an autocomplete option that would insert code beyond the reformatting guide, e.g.

(Here inserting the entirety of .foregroundStyle(...) will definitely exceed that vertical line)
Xcode will try to insert line breaks wherever possible. In this case the result is:
Text("Foo")
    .foregroundStyle(
        <#T##style: ShapeStyle##ShapeStyle#>
    )


You can also do this manually using the "Reformat to Width" menu item, under the "Editor -> "Structure" menu.
